# CSV insertion using SQLCMD, how to do it?

Tags: csv, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert, sqlcmd, csv-import

I have been reading a lot of forums and tutorials where other users ask the same but the answer is almost the same always: use **BCP.EXE (BULK INSERT)** instead to import, and also export with **BCP.EXE** using native format.

But in some post I read that there is a (complicated) way to do it with SQLCMD, and my need now is strongly requesting me to to it through **SQLCMD** as the target is an **Azure SQL DB**. Does anyone know the steplist to follow? Or any useful resource that can share with me?

Thank you very much in advance.

I'm expecting to use only **SQLCMD** to insert the **CSV** data into an **Azure SQL DB**.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use **SQLCMD** to *convert* data:

```
sqlcmd -S ipdb -U sa -P "passwordsa" -d dbname -Q "select * from tabelname" -o "direktori/file.csv" -s"," -W -w 700
```

Or **BCP** to *import* data:

```
bcp Tablename in ~/filename.txt -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password> -d Databasename -c -t  ','
```

Why don't you use SSMS to import the CSV?

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The thing is that currently we are using SSMS and locally it works perfect, but now we need to use an Azure SQL DB instead of the local one, and we need to automate the process with PowerShell. Any other idea? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Azure Data Factory